# TensorFlow: weighted sum of high dimension tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I got a 3 dimension tensor `input` with shape`(batch_size, dim_a, dim_b)`.

If I have a `weight` vector with shape `(batch_size, dim_a)`, and want to get weighted sum of input, `weighted_sum` of shape `(batch_size, dim_b)`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape your weight vector and make use of `tf.reduce_sum`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.random.rand(5, 3, 2)
b = np.random.rand(5, 3)

input = tf.constant(a)
weight = tf.constant(b)
C = input * weight.reshape((5, 3, 1)) # Reshape and multiply weights and input
weighted_sum = tf.reduce_sum(C, axis=1) # Sum along dim_a
weighted_sum.shape

Out[9]: TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(2)])
```